# How do you enable SSL for WCF webHttpBinding AJAX Ajax Enabled Service?

Tags: ajax, wcf

I have a WCF webHttpBinding AJAX Enabled Service that I need to configure for SSL. SSL is turned on at the server. I know how to do this for basicHttpBinding but don't for webHttpBinding. My config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.TestsServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.TestsServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Services.TestsService" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```